# How to check from which button I called form in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have "formA" and 2 buttons on it (button1 and button2). What I want to do is:
When I click on button1 to call "formB" display text written in label1.
When I click button2 to call the same form ("formB") hide label1 and display label2.

The problem is that I don't know how to check what button is clicked on "formA".

Edit: Thanks very much folks for the quick answer. Problem is solved!

Comment: Are you using a common buttonClick event handler, or are you using seperate click events for each button.

Answer (score 4):

This is where events come in handy:

```
public class FormA
{
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        formB.Button1WasClicked();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        formB.Button2WasClicked();
    }
}

public class FormB
{
    public void Button1WasClicked()
    {
        label2.Visible = false;
        label1.Visible = true;
        label1.Text = "Button 1 was clicked!";
    }

    public void Button2WasClicked()
    {
        label1.Visible = false;
        label2.Visible = true;
        label2.Text = "Button 2 was clicked!";
    }
}
```

`button1` and `button2` have their own separate Click event handlers. This way we can differentiate the two when they are clicked.

If you have the same event handler for both buttons (as mentioned in one of the comments), you can identify them with the `sender` parameter using:

```
Object.ReferenceEquals(sender, button1);
```

or

```
Object.ReferenceEquals(sender, button2);
```

Then your code would look like this:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(sender, button1))
    {
        formB.Button1WasClicked();
    }
    else
    {
        formB.Button2WasClicked();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

FormB can't find out, the buttons are a private implementation details of FormA.  They might not even be a button, surely you are going to add a menu or a toolbar to FormA some day.

The workaround becomes much simpler if you stop thinking of "calling a form".  You never call a form, you *create* an instance of it.  And then you make it visible by calling its Show() method.  Lots of things you can do in between those two steps.

Add a public method to FormB.  For lack of a better name:

```
public void MakeLabel2Visible() {
    this.label1.Visible = false;
    this.label2.Visible = true;
}
```

Now it becomes simple.  Implement button2's Click event handler like this:

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        var frm = new FormB();
        frm.MakeLabel2Visible();
        frm.Show();
    }
```

Adding another constructor to a form that lets you initialize it differently is another very common approach.  These are just classes, standard programming techniques are appropriate.

Comment: Actually I aready have both, menu and toolbar, i just wanted to make it simple when explaining the problem. Thanks very much for the code, it helped me!

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using winforms you can do all this very easily due to the fact that you have a stateful environment.

Assuming a very basic set up with:

- event handlers in the code behind of form a
- a reference to an instance of form b in form a (or the button click creating such an instance)
- a method to use in form b to pass it data

Your code will be something like this:

```
public partial class FormA : Form
{
    private FormB formB;

    public FormA()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (formB == null || formB.IsDisposed)
        {
            formB = new FormB();
        }

        formB.UpdateLabel("Button A");
        formB.Show();
    }


    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (formB == null || formB.IsDisposed)
        {
            formB = new FormB();
        }

        formB.UpdateLabel("Button B");
        formB.Show();
    }
}

public partial class FormB : Form
{
    public FormB()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void UpdateLabel(string message)
    {
        label1.Text = message;
    }
}
```

Of course, there are lots of improvements to this - using events and alerts more intelligently and refactoring to remove duplication, but this is a basic example of the sort of things you can do.